# make a loop to display an image according to the value of a class for each element

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to make a function that would apply automatically to all div having a particular class on my document.This should then check the presence of a specific class and display me in that same div an image.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName(".try").foreach({
    if(element.classList.contains(".lol"))
{
        <img src=""/>;
    }
    else {<img src=""/>}
});
```

I know it lacks something to work, but what?
If someone can give me int or a doc that would explain how to do it, I would be more than thankful.

```
<div class="try lol"></div>
<div class="try "> </div>
<div class="try lol"></div>
```

I want the function to check every div with the class try and check if their lol with it, lol is present I want the function to put in the div an image.
I want to use a loop because I have a lot div where try will be and I will put different variable of the next div class for showing another image.
like if its lol show image 1,
if it's lol2 show image 2

Comment: There is no method called `foreach` on [`HTMLCollection`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). There is, however, a method called [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on [`NodeList`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. How is this `<img src=""/>` expression used?

Comment: Your code is not valid javascript. Try adding a minimal, reproducible example in your question to allow others to understand what you are trying to do and provide you a working solution.

Comment: You cannot simply write the HTML tag in the JavaScript code; you will have to use `document.createElement('img')` and set the `src` attribute. An alternative (an I think better) approach, could be to code the default image in the HTML and change the `src` attribute only for the class `.lol`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at how Javascript works. `getElementsByClassName` is an HTMLCollection and doesnt have the function `forEach`. To access the forEach method you need to do something like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(".try")).forEach(element => {
  your code here..
})
```

Also you cannot render html in your javascript file/code. you need to create a new element like:

```
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "...";
element.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive. `foreach` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the images via JavaScript:

```js
const defaultImgSrc = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/468/winter-wonderland-1383617.jpg';
const lolImgSrc = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/1c9/maine-at-4-45-am-1370871.jpg'

document.querySelectorAll('.try').forEach(item => {
  const imgEl = document.createElement('img');
  imgEl.src = item.classList.contains('lol') ? lolImgSrc : defaultImgSrc
  item.append(imgEl);
});
```

```html
<div class="try">
  <p>1</p>
</div>

<div class="try lol">
  <p>2</p>
</div>

<div class="try">
  <p>3</p>
</div>

<div class="try">
  <p>4</p>
</div>

<div class="try lol">
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```

or have the "default" ones already in the HTML and only change the `src` attribute of the ones whose parent has the `lol` class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.lol').forEach(item => {
  item.querySelector('img').src = 'https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/1c9/maine-at-4-45-am-1370871.jpg';
});
```

```html
<div class="try">
  <p>1</p>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/468/winter-wonderland-1383617.jpg">
</div>

<div class="try lol">
  <p>2</p>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/468/winter-wonderland-1383617.jpg">
</div>

<div class="try">
  <p>3</p>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/468/winter-wonderland-1383617.jpg">
</div>

<div class="try">
  <p>4</p>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/468/winter-wonderland-1383617.jpg">
</div>

<div class="try lol">
  <p>5</p>
  <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/468/winter-wonderland-1383617.jpg">
</div>
```